# Illuminate Database outside Laravel with Phinx for migrations

Tags: php, mysql, illuminate-container, phinx

I'm working on a project where I'm using Illuminate's database component outside of Laravel 4.2 and trying to use Phinx for migrations from the command line.  I've set up my database environments in the phinx.yml file for production, development, and my local, which I named "vagrant".  When I try to run the "php vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e vagrant" it comes backs saying "Could not determine database name! Please specify a database name in your config file."  I've tried multiple times to figure out what's causing it, the database name is correct.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: did you confiugure the phinx.yml file?

Comment: That was exactly my problem, sort of.  I configured it in the package's phyinx.php, not the new one that was created in the root directory when i created the project. Thanks for making me double check!

Comment: That part is a bit missing in the phinx documents..http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/configuration.html.

Comment: Also be sure "there is no public access" that phinx.yml file..